# Is it necessary to instal both mysql-server and mysql-client?

Tags: mysql, debian

I'm wondering if it's really necesssay install both packets for LAMP. Phpmyadmin and teminal mysql works without mysql-client.

Comment: How are you defining mysql-client so that it is different than terminal mysql?

Comment: in rare cases you need the DOs/shell comand based commands. the additional connector for different languages you can install when you need it. so comad prompt yes, workbench i like it